# is it possible to make multiple mongo routers connected to just one shard on a mongoDB shard cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'd like to make a mongo cluster with multiple mongo routers(mongos) with just one shard(mongod) like this figure.

**[image]**

So I made two mongo routers named 'mongorouter-1', 'mongorouter-2', and also made one shard named 'mongod'.
In mongorouter-1 I added 'mongod' well with this command.
`sh.addShard("mongod:27017")`
It works well, but In mongorouter-2 this command put an error, like

```
mongos> sh.addShard("mongod:27017")
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.system.version index: _id_ dup key: { : \"shardIdentity\" }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "codeName" : "DuplicateKey",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1558591937, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1558591937, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

In mongorouter-1, sh.status is this

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5ce6683cc490bfc9325389cb")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "mongod:27017",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "4.0.6" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
```

and in mongorouter-2, sh.status is this

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5ce668176a4dcc52fd230ac9")
  }
  shards:
  active mongoses:
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
```

I don't know how to make multiple mongo routers connected to just one shard.
If you know the solution, help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [recommended setup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/_images/sharded-cluster-production-architecture.bakedsvg.svg) colocates mongos with application not with config servers. The diagram is slightly wrong since 3 config servers should be deployed within single replset so there are few arrows missing between them. The setup is rather unusual so you may need to describe it in details. Ideally with something like docker-compose and ask it somewhere on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Alex Blex, let me ask on dba.stackexchange.com with more detail.